# Cannot use react-navigation-tabs in react native application giving an issue of module not found?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Problem:**

I have created a react native application there I am using the react-navigation-tab module. But It causing an error which says this.

> Unable to resolve "react-native-reanimated" from "node_modules\react-navigation-tabs\lib\module\views\MaterialTopTabBar.js

This is my package.json file.

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.8",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.8",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.0",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I tried lot to find a solution to this problem on the internet but I was unable to do so. Can someone help me to solve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You need to in add ["react-native-reanimated"](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-reanimated) library also as described in [react navigation site](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html)

Try this

```
yarn add react-native-reanimated
# or with npm

cd ios
pod install
```